# Project for iOS 12.x using Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm fairly new to Xcode/iOS development and cannot work out how to create a project for a version of iOS older than 13.2.

During the process of creating a project there is no iOS version option & the default is 13.2 which is later than 12.x for which I need to develop.

I can change the supported version after the project has been created but at that point the initial code, a lot of which is only supported by 13.0 & above has been created and thus will not build for 12.x.

Is there some method of getting Xcode to default to building projects for iOS 12.x?

Comment: There is no way (in Xcode 11) but it can't be ***a lot of*** iOS 13+ code

Comment: there is many fake converters on internet but they will never work so u have to do it manually there is no other way ... :(

Comment: There are 24 errors generated. Possibly trivial to work around for experienced Swift coders but I'm not one of those. Because this is in the foundations of the project I cannot experiment to try and fix errors without fixing all errors and that makes it none trivial for me at least.